# How to implement this even-odd matrix decomposition efficiently?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, performance

Note: This question has also been asked on stackoverflow  - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197910/how-to-implement-this-even-odd-matrix-decomposition-efficiently?noredirect=1#comment100975572_57197910

In connection with solving a partial differential equation numerically, I have come across the following question about how to implement a specific matrix-vector product algorithm efficiently in Matlab. For notational convenience I will formulate the question using Matlab notation.

The background of the question is that I have a matrix, D, which has size NxN (N is even and typical values for N are 4, 6 and 8) and which has the property that

```
D(i,j) = - D(N+1-i, N+1-j)
```

for 1 <= i,j <= N. To solve the differential equation, I use a numerical method that requires D to be multiplied onto many different vectors and I therefore want to exploit the above property to make the matrix-vector product as efficient as possible.

The algorithm which utilizes the symmetry of D that I have in mind is the following: Assume we want to compute the product D*f where f is a Nx1 column vector. Moreover, define the column vectors e and o of size N/2x1 by

```
e(n) = 0.5*(f(n) + f(N+1-n))

o(n) = 0.5*(f(n) - f(N+1-n))
```

as well as the matrices De and Do of size N/2xN/2 by

```
De(n,m) = D(n,m) + D(n,N+1-m)

Do(n,m) = D(n,m) - D(n,N+1-m).
```

Using the definition of a matrix-vector product it can be shown that the matrix vector product D * f can be computed as

```
Df = [De*e + Do*o; -De*e + Do*o]
```

and since the products De * e and Do * o each require one quarter as many multiplications as the product D * f I hope that it is possible to reduce the computational time by roughly a factor of 2 using this algorithm.

So far I have, however, not been able to implement the algorithm in a way such that it is faster than the built in matrix-vector product which does not utilize the special property of D. The first hirdle seems to be constructing the vectors e and o. If I do it the straight forward way, i.e.

```
e = 0.5*(f(1:N/2) + flipud(f(N/2+1:N)))

o = 0.5*(f(1:N/2) + flipud(f(N/2+1:N)))
```

it already takes more than an order of magnitude longer than to compute D * f directly. Forming the sparse matrices eMat and oMat as

```
eMat = 0.5*[1, 0, ..., 0, 0, ..., 0, 1;

            0, 1, ..., 0, 0, ..., 1, 0;

            |  |   |   |  |   |   |  |

            0, 0, ..., 1, 1, ..., 0, 0]


oMat = 0.5*[1, 0, ..., 0,  0, ...,  0, -1;

            0, 1, ..., 0,  0, ..., -1,  0;

            |  |    |   |  |    |   |   |

            0, 0, ..., 1, -1, ...,  0, 0]
```

where the vertical lines mean that the pattern should be continued, e and o can be computed as

```
e = eMat*f

o = oMat*f
```

and this takes about a third of the time it takes computing D * f directly. Using the sparse matrices eMat and oMat I can compute De * e and Do * o as

```
Dee = De*eMat*f

Doo = Do*oMat*f
```

and this also takes roughly a third of the time it takes computing D * f with the built in matrix-vector product. Now the difficulty arises, because carrying out the computation

```
Dee + Doo
```

requires about the same amount of time (and typically even a little more) than computing D * f directly. Needless to say, it also takes more time to compute D * f as

```
Df = [Dee + Doo; -Dee + Doo]
```

than with the built in matrix-vector product.

My question is if anyone can suggest a way of implementing the above algorithm efficiently in Matlab, such that the algorithm in total runs faster than the built in matrix-vector product?

Comment: For small $N$, ($N \leq 8$) I do not think that a pure MATLAB implementation can be much faster than `D*f`; on the contrary a C implementation could give the expected speedup. Is writing a mex file an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### statement of problem

The OP question is how to compute efficiently the dense matrix-vector
product $Df$ where $D\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, with the property

$$
D = -J\,D\,J
$$

and $J$ is the $N\times N$ [exchange
matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix). Assumptions
are that matrix $D$ is constant and $N$ even and small.

While reading the OP it occurred to me that the rows of `Emat` and
`Omat` are the eigenvectors of the exchange matrix associated to the
eigenvalues $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = -1$, respectively, and that
after renormalization the eigenvectors are orthonormal. Therefore the
OP algorithm can be rewritten as

$$
V \, (\frac14 V^T\,D\,V) \, V^T f
$$

with

$
\newcommand\iddots{\mathinner{
  \kern1mu\raise1pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise4pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise7pt{\Rule{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}.}
  \kern1mu
}}
$

$$
V = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 &  1 &  0 & \cdots  &  0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots  & 0 &  0 &  1 & \cdots  &  0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots  &   &    &    & \ddots  &  0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots  & 1 &  0 &  0 & \cdots  &  1 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots  & 1 &  0 &  0 & \cdots  & -1 \\
0 & 0 & \iddots &   &    &    & \iddots &  0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots  & 0 &  0 & -1 & \cdots  &  0 \\
1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & -1 &  0 & \cdots  &  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and noting that $V^T V = V V^T = 2 I$

It is easy to show that $V^T\,D\,V$ is block northeast-to-southwest
diagonal, i.e.

$$
V^T\,D\,V
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & D_1 \\
D_2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $D_i$ have dimensions $N/2 \times N/2$.

It is therefore confirmed that it is possible to rewrite $Df$ so that a $N\times N$ matrix-vector product is substituted by two $N/2 \times N/2$ products, with a theoretical speedup of 2.

### MATLAB implementation

The idea here is to use a [function closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) to construct a function handle `mfh` that computes `D*f`. In MATLAB this is obtained with nested functions: the outer scope computes the constant matrices $V, D_1, D_2$, while the inner function `mf` computes the $V^T f$ decomposition, the two dense matrix-vector products, and the $V\cdot$ composition.

```
function mfh = makemf(D)

[N,M] = size(D);
assert(N==M);

HN = round(N/2);
HN1 = HN + 1;

V = sparse(N,N);
for i = 1:HN
    V(i,i) = 1;
    V(N+1-i,i) = 1;
    V(i,HN+i) = 1;
    V(N+1-i,HN+i) = -1;
end

D1 = V(:,1:HN)'*D*V(:,HN1:end) / 4;
D2 = V(:,HN1:end)'*D*V(:,1:HN) / 4;

    function y = mf(x)
        x = V'*x;
        y = zeros(size(x));
        y(1:HN,:) = D1*x(HN1:end);
        y(HN1:end,:) = D2*x(1:HN);
        y = V*y;
    end

mfh = @mf;

end
```

This function returns a function handle `mf` so that `mf(f) == D*f`. E.g.

```
>> N = 8;
>> D = randn(N);
>> D = flipud(D) - fliplr(D);
>> f = randn(N,1);
>> mf = makemf(D);
>> norm(mf(f) - D*f) / norm(D*f)

ans =

   1.9575e-16
```

### timings

Now some timings of `mf(f)` (labelled 'odd even decom.') against `D*f` (labelled 'direct') for `N` from 8 to 8000.

[image: run times]

and the speedup

[image]

Timings where obtained with [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html)

```
t = @() D*f;
timeit(t);
t = @() mf(f);
timeit(t);
```

The bottom line is that this implementation attains the expected asymptotics for $N > 1000$ and that for $N=8000$ the measured speedup is very close to the theoretical one.

### closing comments

This is a late answer that I wrote mainly for fun. In fact it is expected that the theoretical asymptotics can be reached only for medium sized matrices, and that in pure MATLAB for very small $N$ there is no way to speed up `D*f`.

Nevertheless I hope that some useful programming techniques are demonstrated in this answer:

- function closures,
- preallocation of output arrays (avoid constructs like `[D_1*y_1; D_2*y_2]` but first create an empty $N$ array and then assign to its $N/2$ portions),
- sparse matrices.

I think that for $N=10$ the only way to obtain a significative speedup would be a C function inside a MEX file.

Comment: That is a very impressive answer that uses quite a few tricks I was not aware of! Thank you for your time and your help!

Comment: Indeed, nice answer!